# Loop an existing script

Tags: python, loops, import, python-import

I'm using a script from a third party I  can't modify or show (let's call it original.py) which takes a file and produces some calculations. At the end it ouputs a result (using the print statment).

Since I have many files I decided to make a second script that gets all wanted files and runs them through the original.py

1st get list of all files to run

2nd run each file through the original.py

3rd obtain results from each file

I have the 1st and 2nd step. However, the end result only saves the calculations from the last file it read.

```
import sys
import original
import glob
import os

fn=str(sys.argv[1])

for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
   print(filename)

ficheiros = [f for f in glob.glob(fn)]

for ficheiro in ficheiros:
    original.file = bytes(ficheiro,'utf-8')
    original.function()
```

To summarize:
Knowing I can't change the original script (which is made with a print statement) how can I obtain the results for each loop? Is there a better way than using a for loop?.

The first script can be invoked with python original.py
 It requires the file to be changed manually inside the script in the original.file line.

This script outputs the result in the console and I redirect it with: python original.py > result.txt

At the moment when I try to run my script, it reads all the correct files in the folder but only returns the results for the last file.

#
(I tried to reformulate the question hopefully it's easier to understand)

#

The problem is due to a mistake in the ````ficheiros = [f for f in glob.glob(fn)]`````it's only reading one file, hence only outputting one result.

Thanks for the time.sleep() trick in the comments.

### Solved:

I changed the initial part to:

```
fn=str(sys.argv[1])

ficheiros= []
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
   ficheiros.append(filename)
   #print(filename)
```

and now it correctly reads all the files and it outputs all the results

Comment: Is the function you are calling printing or returning the value? It sounds like it is printing so I'm not sure what you mean by overwriting the printed value?

Comment: I understand that you can't show us `original.py`, but can you show us how you would otherwise use it? Would you do `python original.py inputFile.txt` on the command line?

Comment: If it's really printing the value, not returning it, that would be the first time I've seen overwriting `sys.stdout` (and therefore ugly redirecting the output - but it should snatch the prints!) could be useful...

Comment: In the `for ficheiro in ficheiros: original.function()` you iterate over the files, but the `original.function` doesn't get this information. Maybe `original.function(ficheiro)`?

Comment: to run the original script its just python original.py. its does not have any arguments. The file it uses needs to be changed manually inside the script. It prints directly the results in the console and I redirect it with a  >file.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your operating system there are different ways to take what is printed to the console and append it to a file.

For example on Linux, you could run this file that calls original.py for every file `python yourfile.py >> outputfile.txt`, which will then effectively save everything that is printed into outputfile.txt.

The syntax is similar for Windows.

Comment: Yes, the problem is it only prints the calculations for the last read-file. It will not print the results from all the previous files. The loop output is not being correctly printed

Comment: Can you try adding a time.sleep(5) inside the loop `for fichiero in fichieros` and just see the output in the console. Do you get the results for file 1 then overwritten with the results for file 2, etc. each iteration of the loop?

Comment: I see. there is something wrong with the ````ficheiros = [f for f in glob.glob(fn)] ````statement. It is only reading the first file it finds so obviously it will not print the rest. Thanks now I found the problem

Comment: @bvm Glad it worked. If any of the answers were helpful please feel free to accept it or up-vote it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but you could try one of these:

Either redirecting all output to a file for later use, by running the script like so: `python secondscript.py > outfilename.txt`

Or, and this might or might not work for you, redefining the print command to a function that outputs the result how you want, eg:

```
def print(x):
    with open('outfile.txt','w') as f:
        f.write('example: ' + x)
```

If you choose the second option, I recommend saving the old print function (`oldprint = print`) so you can restore and use the regular print later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got exactly what you want. You have a first script named `original.py` which takes some arguments and returns things in the form of `print` statements and you would like to grab these prints statements in your scripts to do things?

If so, a solution could be the `subprocess` module:
Let's say that this is `original.py`:

```
print("Hi, I'm original.py")
print("print me!")
```

And this is `main.py`:

```
import subprocess

script_path = "original.py"
print("Executing ", script_path)

process = subprocess.Popen(["python3", script_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in process.stdout:
    print(line.decode("utf8"))
```

You can easily add more arguments in the `Popen` call like `["arg1", "arg2",]` etc.

Output:

```
Executing  original.py
Hi, I'm original.py

print me!
```

and you can grab the lines in the `main.py` to do what you want with them.